# Display backend error message after Create call

Tags: error-handling, odata, sapui5

In my controller I have the following code - The problem is when it is error, I want to display exact error that is being passed from backend. But in my error handling function I never get any data. What is wrong here?

***Controller.js***

```
var token = null;
$.ajax({
    url: sServiceURl,
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show(0);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", "Fetch");
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        token = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-CSRF-Token");
        oContext.OdataModel.create("/materialsSet", oContext.Data, null, oContext.submitSuccess.bind(oContext), oContext.submitError.bind(oContext));
    }
});

submitSuccess: function(data, response, oContext) {
     // works fine 
},
submitError: function(oError) {
   // I never get anything in oError, so the below code is useless.
    try {
        if (oError.responseText) {
            obj = JSON.parse(oError.responseText);
            message = obj.error.message.value;
        } else if (oError.response.body) {
            var errorModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
            errorModel.setXML(oError.response.body);
            //Read message node
                    if (errorModel.getProperty("/0/message") !== "") {
                        message = errorModel.getProperty("/0/message");
                    } else {
                        message = message1;
                    }
                } else {
                    message = message1;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                message = message1;
            }
            sap.m.MessageToast.show(message);
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you, first of all check backend response. I have use the below code for **error handling**.

```
submitError: function(responseBody) {
    try {
        var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
        var errorDetails = body.error.innererror.errordetails;
        if (errorDetails) {
            if (errorDetails.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < errorDetails.length; i++) {
                    console.log(errorDetails[i].message);
                }
            } else
                console.log(body.error.message.value);
        } else
            console.log(body.error.message.value);
    } catch (err) {
        try {
            //the error is in xml format. Technical error by framework
            switch (typeof responseBody) {
                case "string": // XML or simple text
                    if (responseBody.indexOf("<?xml") > -1) {
                        var oXML = jQuery.parseXML(responseBody);
                        var oXMLMsg = oXML.querySelector("message");
                        if (oXMLMsg)
                            console.log(oXMLMsg.textContent);
                    } else
                        console.log(responseBody);

                    break;
                case "object": // Exception
                    console.log(responseBody.toString());
                    break;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("common error message");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for resonse, but I still don't get any value in responseBody. It is a gateway error not thrown from backend. Is it why, nothing is passed back in responseBody. Also, in my create statement do you see any way in which I can call submitError function in a way it will return some data

Comment: The gateway has to return the error message, without that you cant get any error response. Thats why the `responseBody` is empty. You can verify the response using _chrome Network TAB_